# What level should I be before facing Vilemaw?

Tags: league-of-legends

With the new treeline, there's the new Spider boss, [Vilemaw](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vilemaw), with a damage buff reward for beating it.

At what level should a team with average equipment try to tackle it? And if I would be to tackle it by myself, what level should I wait for to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all **Vilemaw** is really very strong neutral monster (maybe nerf) who gets harder by every minute of game. General is harder than **Dragon** and weaker than **Baron Nashor**.

I will make a comparision by max health to understand

- *Dragon*: 3200 + (220 * highest champion level)
- *Vilemaw*: [5011 + 280 per player level + 150 per minute](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vilemaw)
- *Baron Nashor*: 9876 + 125 per minute

Dragon health **don't scale per time**. Vilemaw and Baron **scales** making them harder and harder to beat late in game.

Additionaly **Vilemaw damage** also **[scales in time](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vilemaw)**. There aren't any other monster which do that. He have Dragon damage after ~17 minutes and Baron after ~43.

In concluson - **treat it as a challenge like a Baron Nashor**.

Comment: Does he ever stop scaling? As in, is there a certain point in the game where he won't become stronger?

Comment: I don't think so. That is why he is so interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience, 3 team members (Kennen, Teemo, and Jarvin) had no difficulty killing Vilemaw at lvl 15.  Kennen and Teemo were able to kill him and remain at almost full health at lvl 18.

If you were to try to solo Vilemaw, I would recommend an AD Carry with good damage (infinity edge), attack speed (phantom dancer), and life steal (blood thirster).